# Map Array in child in php

Tags: php, php-7

I have 2 arrays in php which look like following:

> array1 = [product_id = [data], product_id = [data], ..]

```
[
    101 => [
        "sku" => "AB01"
    ],
    201 => [
        "sky" => "AB02"
    ],
    ...
]
```

> array2 = attribute of product with product_id

```
    [
    0 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "name" => "pro 1"
    ],
    1 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "size" => "S"
    ],
    2 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "name" => "pro 2"
    ],
    3 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "size" => "S"
    ],
    ...
]
```

What I want is according to product_id in array2 data is pushed in array1 as child array like this

```
    [
    101 => [
        "sku" => "AB01",
        "attributes" => [
            0 => [
                "product_id" => 101,
                "name" => "pro 1"
            ],
            1 => [
                "product_id" => 101,
                "size" => "S"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    201 => [
        "sky" => "AB02",
        "attributes" => [
            0 => [
                "product_id" => 201,
                "name" => "pro 2"
            ],
            1 => [
                "product_id" => 201,
                "size" => "S"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

Array length is around 1000 for array1 and >5000 for array2. foreach loop taking too much time. Is there any fast way to achieve it?

Comment: You say it's taking to much time, can you show how you have tried this?

Comment: @NigelRen could check the answer please if it correct, and thanks

Comment: Sorry - mot sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the fastest way I can think of achieving this is using a foreach loop over the second array, as your first array is indexed by the product_id, it is easy to directly insert the new data on each loop...

```
foreach ( $array2 as $item )    {
    $array1[$item['product_id']]['attributes'][] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you

```
$array1 = [
            101 => [
                "sku" => "AB01"
            ],
            201 => [
                "sky" => "AB02"
            ]
        ];

$array2 = [
            0 => [
                "product_id" => 101,
                "name" => "pro 1"
            ],
            1 => [
                "product_id" => 101,
                "size" => "S"
            ],
            2 => [
                "product_id" => 201,
                "name" => "pro 2"
            ],
            3 => [
                "product_id" => 201,
                "size" => "S"
            ]
        ] ;

foreach ($array2 as $result){
    if(array_key_exists($result['product_id'], $array1)) {
        $array1[$result['product_id']]['attributes'][] = $result;
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

your result look like this

```
Array
(
    [101] => Array
        (
            [sku] => AB01
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 101
                            [name] => pro 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 101
                            [size] => S
                        )

                )

        )

    [201] => Array
        (
            [sky] => AB02
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 201
                            [name] => pro 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 201
                            [size] => S
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1=[
    101 => [
        "sku" => "AB01"
    ],
    201 => [
        "sky" => "AB02"
    ]
];
$arr2=[
    0 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "name" => "pro 1"
    ],
    1 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "size" => "S"
    ],
    2 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "name" => "pro 2"
    ],
    3 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "size" => "S"
    ]
];

foreach ($arr2 as $arr_val ) {
    $arr1[$arr_val['product_id']]['attributes'][] = $arr_val;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer work for you

first array

```
$arr = [
    101 => [
        "sku" => "AB01"
    ],
    201 => [
        "sky" => "AB02"
    ],
];
```

second array

```
$arr2 = [
    0 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "name" => "pro 1"
    ],
    1 => [
        "product_id" => 101,
        "size" => "S"
    ],
    2 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "name" => "pro 2"
    ],
    3 => [
        "product_id" => 201,
        "size" => "S"
    ],
];
```

finally this what i try to do

```
$newArr = [];

forEach($arr as $product_id => $product_value){
    $attrArr = [];
    forEach($arr2 as $key => $value){
        if($product_id == $value['product_id']){

            $attrArr[] = $value;

            $newArr[$product_id] = [
                array_keys($product_value)[0] => array_values($product_value)[0],
            ];
        }

    }
    $newArr[$product_id]['attributes'] = $attrArr;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
echo '</pre>';
```